# GET works but POST doesn't work in PHPStorm

Tags: php, forms, post, get, phpstorm

I have a simple HTML form:

```
 <form class="form-signin" action="formHandler.php" method="post">
                        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Login</h2>
                        </br>
                        </br>
                        <label for="inputUsername" class="sr-only">Benutzername</label>
                        <input type="inputUsername" name="inputUsername" id="inputUsername" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>
                        <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" name="inputPassword" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
                        </br>
                        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="clear">Clear</button>
                    </form>
```

which I send to the following PHP script:

```
var_dump($_POST);
var_dump($_GET);
```

When I use GET, my variables get passed correctly. However, when I use post (as in the example) var_dump($_POST) returns an empty array.

Comment: First, `type="inputUsername"` should be changed to `type="text"`

Comment: @Aniket Sahrawat OP said he did

Comment: @AniketSahrawat: I did. As I said, GET works, POST doesn't.

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy thanks, fixed.

Comment: @Fang I can't see anything fatally wrong which makes POST does not work. Unfortunately you are only showing part of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After extensive searching, I found out that the issue is rooted in PHPStorm's local environment. The POST request works fine when the site is deployed to a local Apache environment or when uploaded to a website.

The problem is documented on IntelliJ website:

[POST Problem with PHPStorm 10.02 and onwards](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206999125-PhPStorm-10-does-not-allow-POST-method)

Jetbrains issuetracker with the issue in question:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-31257